# When I use the 'reserve' operation in beanstalked, it is blocked for a long time

Tags: python, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I need to use beanstalked in my project.So I download the 1.1 version.
I use the beanstalkc for python client.
A simple Producer-Consumer model.

**Producer:**

```
       import beanstalkc
       beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection('localhost')
       beanstalk.use('foo')
       beanstalk.put('hello')
       beanstalk.put('world')
```

**Consumer:**

```
      import beanstalkc
      beanstalk.use('foo')
      beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection('localhost')
      job = beanstalk.reserve()
```

But the reserve operation is blocked for a long time.Has anybody encounter this problem?

Comment: I have resolved this problem.Because the "use" command is for producers.The consumer must be use 'wath' command.The "watch" command adds the named tube to the watch list for the current
connection. A reserve command will take a job from any of the tubes in the
watch list.so   The Consumser                                              import beanstalkc
      beanstalk.watch('foo')
      beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection('localhost')
      job = beanstalk.reserve()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to reserve a job with beanstalkd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818184/unable-to-reserve-a-job-with-beanstalkd)